# threadStatus have a value of "225", what does it mean?

Tags: java, multithreading

Java Thread has a property named `threadStatus`. During my debug , I found it have a value of  225, but cannot find any explanations in Java API document. So who can help me?

I mean this private member of Class **java.lang.Thread**
`private int threadStatus = 0;`

Comment: And the API documentation...

Comment: Is it a private member?

Comment: "private volatile int threadStatus = 0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you have seen is the value of  `private volatile int threadStatus = 0;` which is `volatile` variable of `Thread` class which is initialized to `zero` to indicate that `Thread` not started means in `NEW` state.But when you call the `start()` method of `Thread` value chages to something else say `2` which remains as it is after starting the `Thread` to make sure `start` won't be called again.

So For example when you call `start` twice on any `Thread` it checks for this variable to `!=0` if its `!=0` than throws `IllegalThreadStateException`.

*Value of this variable used at many places to verify Thread has been started.*

Note here that Change in the value occurs internally.

I got following from [Eclipse Community's Senior Member](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/2297/)

> The number is converted via native methods into the *State* enum available in
>   the java api.

Comment: thanks, I debug my code as a remote java application and find this value, so weird...

Answer (score 2):

There in java.lang.Thread is also a Map threadStateNames and another one, threadStateMap, that map the integer value to names and Thread.State objects: consult these. Since these values come from the innards of your local JVM, there is no general documentation of the numeric value, which is apt to depend on your operating system.

Comment: I use JDK1.6 HotSpot 64bit, and cannot find these members, and do u know what is the relationship between **Thread.State** and this private member **threadStatus**?

Comment: I am afraid you'll have to dig into the sources of your JDK version to find an answer. I *suspect* that this number results from the or-ed combination of several enum (int) values, each of which indicates a "facet" of the state. But this is absolutely OS-dependent.